# Moving the cursor to top left corner of the screen in C# Winforms App

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor

I have a MainForm which opens a modal dialog using `ShowDialog()` method.

In that modal dialog class `Form_Load` method I have:

```
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(0, 0);
    }
```

I found above code somewhere in internet searching for information about moving the cursor to 0, 0 position.

If I remove code `this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);`, it also works, moving the cursor to 0, 0 position.

What is that cursor creation used for? should a border condition exist somehow when the app will be used?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: "What is that cursor creation used for?" Nothing. You don't need it.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks, I supposed that, but I found that in the example of this Microsoft site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?view=windowsdesktop-6.0. So I thought if Microsoft uses it, a reason could exist.

Comment: Not everything in the Microsoft documentation actually makes sense, unfortunately.  The comment says, "// Set the Current cursor", which it does...but it sets the cursor to the same cursor that already exists, which is kinda pointless...

Comment: It's just an example that shows some features: how to change the icon of the Cursor, move it to a new location and clip it to a region (so you can use the same code sample in some other contexts). That's all.

Comment: You should not move the mouse cursor by code even less to a screen coordinate. User with multiple large 4K screen will find your feature very annoying...